# How to use bi-directional relationship on large amounts of data

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

We have a DB with about 15m text based records (lets call them the parent) that are about 10kb in size each. The parent has many one way relationships to other objects (owner, tags, company) etc. This works well as when we load in a single parent we don't unintentionally load in the rest of the database.

However we have an issue where when a related record (such as company) gets updated, this change is not reflected in the index of the parent. From reading other issues I see this is a common problem and we just need to add in a bi-directional relationship, which we have done. For example on the company we now have a ManyToOne relationship with the parent record. The issue with this is if we lazily load we get an error when trying to update the list of parents, as it hasn't been instantiated. If we eagerly load suddenly we load a large portion of our database in, which is extremely slow and prone to out of memory exceptions.

How should we structure this to avoid these issues. Is there another way to use / alternative to the containedin annotation? If not how can we maintain the bi-directional relationship without killing performance?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment the best solution would be to keep the association unidirectional and to disable automatic indexing for associations to the `Company` entity. When your application changes such "reference" data, set a flag somewhere, and plan reindexing of the affected entities overnight, for example using the [mass indexer](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexing-massindexer) or even a [manual batch process](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-indexing-manual).

[This section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/6.0/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-reindexing-reindexonupdate-shallow) of the documentation is relevant.

In the future, there are plans to introduce asynchronous indexing to Hibernate Search, so that it would be able to perform this "delayed" reindexing without your help. We're not there yet, though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. The shallow update stuff looks good, my only concern is sometimes this reference data itself can change fairly frequently. For example we have one such reference data called {Application}, which has text fields with application contacts which change semi-regularly. Parent to Application is a ManyToOne relationship, and each applications can have up to hundreds of thousands of Parent recrods tied to it. If we want the changes to the Application to apply to the Parent index is our best bet to still keep it unidirectional, and just manually re-index during down time?

Comment: @HibernateIndexIssues Yes that's your best bet. Hibernate Search indexes in the same session where the changes occurred, so it cannot (currently) handle re-indexing very large amounts of entities automatically. If you need the changes to be taken into account faster, you can keep track of modified companies, push their ID to a queue and run a background process of yours that will reindex the corresponding entities ASAP, in a separate session with periodic calls to `session.clear()`. But still, that's a lot of data to reindex, so be careful what you wish for :)